# What's the memory layout of UTF-16 encoded strings with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: windows, utf-16, wstring

WinAPI uses `wchar_t` buffers. As I understand we need to use UTF-16 to encode all our arguments to WinAPI.

We have two versions of UTF-16: `UTF-16be` and `UTF-16le`. Let encode a string "Example" `0x45 0x78 0x61 0x6d 0x70 0x6c 0x65`. With UTF-16be bytes should be placed as this: `00 45 00 78 00 61 00 6d 00 70 00 6c 00 65`. With UTF-16le it should be `45 00 78 00 61 00 6d 00 70 00 6c 00 65 00`. (We are omitting BOM). Byte representations of the same string are different.

According to the docs Windows uses `UTF-16le`. This means that we should encode all strings with UTF-16le or it would not work.

At the same time my compiler (VS2015) uses `UTF-16be` for the strings that I hard coded into my code (smth like `L"my test string"`). But WinAPI works well with these strings. Why it works? What am I missing?

**Update 1:**

To test byte representation of hard coded strings I used following code:

```
std::string charToHex(wchar_t ch)
{
    const char alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    std::string result(4, ' ');

    result[0] = alphabet[static_cast<unsigned int>((ch & 0xf000) >> 12)];
    result[1] = alphabet[static_cast<unsigned int>((ch & 0xf00) >> 8)];
    result[2] = alphabet[static_cast<unsigned int>((ch & 0xf0) >> 4)];
    result[3] = alphabet[static_cast<unsigned int>(ch & 0xf)];

    return std::move(result);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that VS2015 is creating `UTF-16be` strings? I'm quite sure it isn't.

Comment: @MarkRansom I updated the question. I tested hard coded strings with the code above.

Comment: So what is your sample code generating? Strings like `0045` and `0078` or  like `4500` and `7800`.  It should be generating strings like the former. However that doesn't show what byte order is being using since you're not accessing the string a sequence of bytes, you're accessing it as a sequence of `wchar_t` values. It doesn't show what byte order `wchar_t` values have.

Comment: The snippet makes little sense, std::string cannot store an utf-16 encoded string.  Right now you are just seeing that 0x00 does not display anything on the screen.  You'll have to use std::wstring() to get Chinese.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it follows the pattern: *"<false statement> - Why is this the case, and how to solve it?"*. This is not useful.

Comment: @IInspectable but it has code which shows how the false statement was arrived at, which provides an opportunity to educate the OP. As well as anyone else in the future who has the same confusion.

Comment: @MarkRansom: There are one bazillion ways to write code that doesn't do what you think it does. I don't see, how this question deserves any more attention than the one-bazillion-minus-one others.

Comment: @IInspectable the question demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of a programming concept. If that misunderstanding can be corrected, that's a *good* thing. And if there's any chance that someone in the future could have the same misunderstanding and bump into this question, that's an even better thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little endian or big endian describes the way that variables of more than 8 bits are stored in memory. The test you have devised doesn't test memory layout, it's working with `wchar_t` types directly; the upper bits of an integer type are always the upper bits, no matter if the CPU is big endian or little endian!

This modification to your code will show how it really works.

```
std::string charToHex(wchar_t * pch)
{
    const char alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    std::string result;

    unsigned char * pbytes = static_cast<unsigned char *>(pch);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(wchar_t); ++i)
    {
        result.push_back(alphabet[(pbytes[i] & 0xf0) >> 4];
        result.push_back(alphabet[pbytes[i] & 0x0f];
    }

    return std::move(result);
}
```

Comment: Now I understand how I failed... Thank you very much